# How much should the gravitational force increase to make 8 hours feels like 300 years?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, time-dilation, estimation

How much should the gravitational force increase to make 8 hours feels like 300 years?

Comment: Please clarify on what you mean by "8 hours feels like 300 years". Einstein's special relativity postulates that the laws of physics are true for all reference frames, thus, it is impossible for  somebody to experience time "slowing down" for themselves.

Answer (score 3):

The amount of [gravitational time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation) depends on the [gravitational *potential*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_potential), not the gravitational *force*. For example, in a gravitational well you could have large time dilation but zero force, if the well had a deep region where the potential was constant.

No matter how much time dilation occurs, 8 hours “feels like” 8 hours to you. *Another* observer outside the gravitational well might measure 300 years passing *for them* as 8 hours passes for you. Their 300 years feels like 300 years to them. Nobody ever thinks their own time has slowed down.

Comment: Isn't that dangerous!?